Testing flow of multiple Camunda workflows in a single test case
There are 5 camunda workflows all perform the same operations and have excatly the same behaviour except the names of the workflow.
workflow 1
workflow 2
workflow 3
workflow 4
workflow 5
what i want is to test the flow of the workflow by mocking a sinlge workflow (as all workflows are the same) in single testcase.
i am writing the testcase using spring boot.
could you please tell how i can do this!!??
i m tring to mock workflow 1 using stubfor wiremock function.while defining the other workflow in a single test funtion.
